# My Unity Game On IOS Get Close and cant Open after almost a week

Tags: ios, firebase, unity-game-engine, google-cloud-firestore, cocoapods

when I build there is no error on unity or Xcode, even it has no problem on devices for almost one week, but after that, it crashes on startup every time.
we use firebase services, Appodeal, and Game analytics.

here is the crash log on the main thread :

```
    Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  UnityFramework                 0x1c388 CrashedCheckBelowForHintsWhy + 116 (CrashReporter.mm:116)
1  UnityFramework                 0x15d4240 UnhandledExceptionHandler_CUSTOM_iOSNativeUnhandledExceptionHandler(ScriptingBackendNativeStringPtrOpaque*, ScriptingBackendNativeStringPtrOpaque*, ScriptingBackendNativeStringPtrOpaque*) + 104 (StringStorageDefault.h:104)
2  UnityFramework                 0x24edde8 firebase::firestore::csharp::TransactionManagerInternal::ExecuteCallbackFromMainThread(std::__1::unique_ptr<firebase::firestore::csharp::TransactionCallback, std::__1::default_delete<firebase::firestore::csharp::TransactionCallback> >*) (.cold.1) + 4462255592
3  UnityFramework                 0x47934 RuntimeInvoker_TrueVoid_t700C6383A2A510C2CF4DD86DABD5CA9FF70ADAC5_RuntimeObject_RuntimeObject(void (*)(), MethodInfo const*, void*, void**) + 32902 (Il2CppInvokerTable.cpp:32902)
4  UnityFramework                 0x1e24e98 il2cpp::vm::Runtime::Invoke(MethodInfo const*, void*, void**, Il2CppException**) + 576 (Runtime.cpp:576)
5  UnityFramework                 0x1e257dc il2cpp::vm::Runtime::CallUnhandledExceptionDelegate(Il2CppDomain*, Il2CppDelegate*, Il2CppException*) + 811 (Runtime.cpp:811)
6  UnityFramework                 0x1e2576c il2cpp::vm::Runtime::UnhandledException(Il2CppException*) + 669 (Runtime.cpp:669)
7  UnityFramework                 0x1f31478 ScriptingInvocation::Invoke(ScriptingExceptionPtr*, bool) (.cold.1) + 8384
8  UnityFramework                 0x156bd50 ScriptingInvocation::ScriptingInvocation(ScriptingMethodPtr) + 29 (ScriptingInvocation.cpp:29)
9  UnityFramework                 0x15789f4 MonoBehaviour::CallUpdateMethod(int) + 518 (MonoBehaviour.cpp:518)
10 UnityFramework                 0x13a9ab4 void BaseBehaviourManager::CommonUpdate<BehaviourManager>() + 178 (Behaviour.cpp:178)
11 UnityFramework                 0x146e408 ExecutePlayerLoop(NativePlayerLoopSystem*) + 383 (PlayerLoop.cpp:383)
12 UnityFramework                 0x146e448 ExecutePlayerLoop(NativePlayerLoopSystem*) + 407 (PlayerLoop.cpp:407)
13 UnityFramework                 0x146e714 PlayerLoop() + 510 (PlayerLoop.cpp:510)
14 UnityFramework                 0x19326cc UnityPlayerLoopImpl(bool) + 332 (LibEntryPoint.mm:332)
15 UnityFramework                 0x185a4 -[UnityAppController(Rendering) repaint] + 232 (UnityAppController+Rendering.mm:232)
16 UnityFramework                 0x1850c -[UnityAppController(Rendering) repaintDisplayLink] + 72 (UnityAppController+Rendering.mm:72)
17 QuartzCore                     0x1009c CA::Display::DisplayLink::dispatch_items(unsigned long long, unsigned long long, unsigned long long) + 760
18 QuartzCore                     0x165bc display_timer_callback(__CFMachPort*, void*, long, void*) + 368
19 CoreFoundation                 0xa60c __CFMachPortPerform + 172
20 CoreFoundation                 0x4a45c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 56
21 CoreFoundation                 0x4da4c __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 588
22 CoreFoundation                 0xb060 __CFRunLoopRun + 2376
23 CoreFoundation                 0x1dd8c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 572
24 GraphicsServices               0x19a0 GSEventRunModal + 160
25 UIKitCore                      0x4ee018 -[UIApplication _run] + 1080
26 UIKitCore                      0x28229c UIApplicationMain + 2060
27 UnityFramework                 0x17ff0 -[UnityFramework runUIApplicationMainWithArgc:argv:] + 96 (main.mm:96)
28 KolayKelime                    0x7e00 main + 28 (main.mm:28)
29 ???                            0x1026c0190 (Missing)
```

Comment: Do you have a free developer membership?  If so then you need to reinstall your app every seven days. Builds by paid memberships are valid for longer.

Comment: thank you for your response @Paulaw11 
Do you mean unity membership? I have a unity plus subscription.

Comment: No, Apple Developer program membership

Comment: @paulw11 I think I have paid memberships but since it is under another account, Can you give me a guide to how can I check, please.

Comment: You need to log in to the apple developer portal to check your expiration date and status.  How are you signing and distributing the app?  Are you using some sort of side loading website?

Comment: @paulw11 
No, I am using Xcode.
In Developer Portal :
Program Type: Apple Developer Program
Entity Type : Company / Organization
Expiration Date:  June 2022
Your Roles: AppManager Reporter

Comment: Then your builds should be valid for at least six months. So, to confirm, you plug your device into your Mac and build and run the app from Xcode?

Comment: Yes, No Problem It works without any error for 5 or six days.
then crash on open. and even it's already on the app store, however, download it from the store same thing happens.

Comment: The stack trace indicates that there is a crash in Firestore. So maybe, there is a data problem?  Look at the lines in the stack trace and see if you can work out what your app is doing when it crashes.

Comment: @paulw11 Thank you for Your Informations, Can you understand this log?! I can't find which code and which line!!! it just keeps refreshing .h files from frameworks and main.mm is loading unity framework at line 28